# PKCS #11: Is C_Login done per session or not ?

Tags: security, pkcs#11

I'm working with PKCS#11 library in multithreaded app. I expected that C_Login must be done for each C_OpenSession to work with sensitive content. But it appears that when one thread has logged in, all following calls to C_Login return ALREADY_LOGGED error.
The app is multithreaded and if one thread has provided the PIN all other threads serving another users may access the hardware content.

Is this by PKCS#11 design and can I rely on this behavior or just poor implementation?

Answer (score 6):

It is by design that `C_Login` and `C_Logout` functions globally change the state of all sessions (even those that are yet to be opened). See chapter 6.7 of [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/raw/master/v2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf) for more details.